# Problem obtaining IP address when connecting to Linksys E4200 with DHCP Reservation established

Tags: dhcp

I am having difficulty acquiring an IP address when running off my Ubuntu
partition and attempting to connect to the Cisco Linksys E4200
wireless router via wireless which is using DHCP reservation for assigning "static"
IP addresses based on the adapter's MAC address .
DHCP reservation is a feature on the E4200 and E3200 routers that sets
certain IP addresses in the pool of DHCP IP address range based on the
MAC address of the adapter.  The IP address assigned is in essence
"fixed" even within the DHCP range.

I am not having problems with this when I boot from the Windows partition.

Also, when I disable DHCP reservation and get an IP address, the
conventional way on the Ubuntu partition, I don't have any problems.
With DHCP reservation set on the router and when  running Ubuntu, I can never get an IP address connecting via
wireless.  I can however get an IP address when I connect via LAN.

I just wonder if I am the only one who has tried this or  anyone else
faced the same problem because I believe everything is set up properly. perhaps
this is an oversight and has not been tested.

Thank you.

Comment: Debug output is going to be essential to troubleshooting this one. Please run `dhclient` when you've connected to the wireless network (but not obtained an IP address), and add the output to your question. Also, it'd be useful to know if fixed DHCP assignments work over a wired connection.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.